# ssh keys requests password while ssh on remote machine

Tags: linux, ssh, git, arch-linux

I have ssh keys setup on my laptop and desktop, so I do not have any issues when I work on either the laptop or the desktop itself. However, when I ssh into the desktop computer and try to git pull or push, I am asked to type the password for the ssh-key.

```
Enter passphrase for key /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519:
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: In order to help you would have to provide the OpenSSH server configuration file.

Comment: @Ramhound certainly not server related, as this is a message about the clients SSH private key. The servers configuration has nothing to do with that, as this happens before the keys are exchanged. Also probably he is using github or a similar service, where he simply does not have access to the servers config files.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to remove the passphrase of your SSH keyfile, or generate a new one. This can be done with [ssh-keygen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/112409/15087622).

```
 -p      Requests changing the passphrase of a private key file instead of creating a new private key.  The program will prompt for the file containing the private key, for the old passphrase, and
             twice for the new passphrase.
```

Entering
`ssh-keygen -p`
will interactively lead you through the process. Simply enter no new passphrase.

If you want to keep the passphrase on your private key, you can also add the key to your systems keyring via `ssh-add -K`